# Обновление программы

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как можно сделать или какой компонент нужен в `DELPHI7`, чтобы можно было обновлять свою программу через интернет?

Например, я создал программу и хочу влить ее на хостинг. Причем, при каждом ее модернизации у пользователей этой программы показывала, что на сервере имеется обновление той или иной моей программы?!

Answer (score 2):

*Вы можете воспользоваться готовыми компонентами для данной задачи.*

Из бесплатных вариантов я бы рекомендовал [`TmxWebUpdate`](http://www.torry.net/vcl/install/webupdate/mxwebupdate121.zip), из коммерческих - [`TMS TWebUpdate`.](http://tmssoftware.com/site/wupdate.asp)

Comment: Благодарен! надеюсь получится буду пробовать делать!!!